# Adding a cite tag within the blockquote tag using redactor's WYSIWYG?

Tags: templating, redactor, wysiwyg, markup

I have a rich text field that needs to have the cite tag within. See here:

[image: redactor in Craft cms]

It is currently ouputting as:

```
<blockquote>
    This is the quote.
</blockquote>
```

Whereas I need to work in an option for the client to create this:

```
<blockquote>
    This is the quote.
    <cite>
        John Doe, Founder
    </cite>
</blockquote>
```

What options are there for formatting some copy to be within the blockquote tag, but then formatting some of it to be wrapped in cite tags?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: We have discussed the options of having this as a matrix, but this rich text field is already within a matrix. And keeping all content-based markup like this within the rich text editor is better for the client, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Redactor Inline Styles](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-redactorinlinestyles) add-on then use the following in your Redactor json config:

```
"plugins": ["source","fullscreen","inlinestyles"],
    "buttonsAddAfter": "italic",
    "buttonsAdd": {
        "cite": {
            "title": "Cite",
            "args": ["cite"]
        }
    }
```

You'll then be able to add a `cite` element within a blockquote formatted text.

Comment: This doesn't work in Craft 3 -- curious if anyone knows how to do this in the latest Redactor version?

Answer (score 1):

Craft [uses Redactor as its rich text editor](https://craftcms.com/docs/rich-text-fields) - Redactor has numerous configuration options, one of which is direct html editing. One option would be to create a new Redactor configuration that includes the `'html'` button.

For example, You could copy Craft's "Standard" Config:

```
{
"buttons": ["format","bold","italic","lists","link","file","horizontalrule"],
"plugins": ["source","fullscreen"]
}
```

Into a new file `myCustomConfig.json` at `craft/config/redactor`, then add the `'html'` button:

```
{
"buttons": ["html","format","bold","italic","lists","link","file","horizontalrule"],
"plugins": ["source","fullscreen"]
}
```

And select your new config from the Settings page. This should allow you to manually edit the html to include `<cite>` tags inside of your `<blockquotes>`.